# alexa doesnot respond to unhandled intent, instead it calls any of my custom intents that I have been created

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, unhandled

I had a intent with  slot value (custom slot type) as utterance and some other intents .whenever I give something unrelated it maps to any of my intents.I used unhandled intent but is never called.please help me why am i getting this scenario?Is there anything that I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this discussion regarding the same issue? https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/43

It looks like people were able to get around this by adding utterances for the UnhandledIntent